# Use Rails Model method in Active Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, methods, model, controller

I have an orde field on one of my models, that model also has a is_milestone? method which returns true or false depending on whether the order is either a 50th or 100th milestone.

I wish to select all the items that are milestones but can this be done by using the is_milestone? method?

I currently have:

```
@milestones = Model.where(:is_milestone?).order('order ASC')
```

But it doesn't work and I think I have the syntax wrong but unsure how it should be written.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - You cannot ask the database to do a query which requires interaction with your Ruby code.

The only way you'd be able to get this to work is to create an `is_milestone` attribute on your model and store the boolean value within the database. You could perhaps populate this value with an `after_save` callback which counted the milestones and set the value to true if it was either the 50th or 100th one.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Going the new field in DB route instead. Thanks!

Comment: I've added the following but the field is not getting set in my DB. Any ideas?

   after_save do |record|
      record.is_milestone = true if record.is_milestone?
   end

Comment: `is_milestone?` is a method which rails will dynamically add to your model because you defined it as a boolean attribute. You should rather test the instance directly in your callback or create a new method with a unique name to perform this test for you.

Comment: Actually is_milestone? is a custom method I have written on my model. Before today I did NOT have a field in my DB called is_milestone

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm suggesting you rename your method to something else, so that when you call `is_milestone?` it will use the dynamic method which tests the boolean value of your models attribute, rather than grabbing all the instances and counting them every single time.